# Stack Overflow site downtime?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Has the site been down for maintenance? Also I do not get any responses on my questions any more. Might that be because of the downtime?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there was some downtime yesterday for maintenance.

This is documented on [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/).

As for why your questions are not getting answers - perhaps they are not clear? Revisit them and add details.

Comment: That is a beautifully succinct and complete answer.